# IOS: UITableView Jerks When Scrolling Up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having this weird issue where my `UITableView` starts jerking or stuttering when scrolling up, but as soon as I scroll up all the way, it is fine. I am using this table view to hold a chat conversation. I am using a custom cell, and it is only populating text on two labels.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MessagesInfo" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //
    // Configure the cell...

    WinMessagesInfoCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MessagesInfo" forIndexPath:indexPath];


        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[WinMessagesInfoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MessagesInfo"];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSNumber *userId = [defaults valueForKey:@"loggedInUserId"];

    NSLog(@"Line 791 WinMessageViewController");

    if ([self.sender_id objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])
    {

        if ([[self.sender_id objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:userId]){
            cell.friendName.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            cell.friendName.text = @"Me";
        }
        else
        {
            cell.friendName.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            cell.friendName.text = [self.from objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        }

        cell.friendMessage.text = [self.message objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    }

        return cell;
  }
```

Update:
This issue appears to be the height of my cells, if I take out the dynamic cell growth, the issue goes away, but I need them to grow dynamically. I am currently using the following:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //minimum size of your cell, it should be single line of label if you are not clear min. then return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

The estimates must be bad. Any advice to get a better estimate? There are two labels in the cell and only one of the labels will change in size.

Comment: First, cell can NEVER be nil so remove that check. Second, you really need to profile this in Instruments to find which bit is taking the time. I suspect that the answer below (although not written well) is correct.

Comment: If I remove that check then the cells aren't created on my table view. I tried the answer below and it did nothing. I also reviewed through instruments and there was no performance drop.

Comment: that isn't true. Read the docs about that dequeue method. It will never return a nil cell. Put a breakpoint inside your cell creation block. It will never be called.

Comment: Regardless, that did not solve the issue.

Comment: no. It wouldn't do. You need to profile your app and find what is taking the time. Nothing in your code looks like it should take a long time so any help now is just a guess.

Comment: What is self.sender_id?